# Must I specify unique Loading booleans when fetching data via multiple async functions within useEffects in React hooks to avoid concurrency problems?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, concurrency, react-hooks

My concern is if using the same `isLoading` boolean state can cause concurrency issues. Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);


  useEffect(() => {
    async function getWaitlistDetailsOnLoad() {
      setIsLoading(true)
      try {
        const details = await getWaitlistDetailsForUser(
          apiInstance,
          product.id
        );
        if (details.status === 200) {
          setWaitlistDetails(details.data);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error getting waitlist details: ", e);
      }
      setIsLoading(false)
    }
    getWaitlistDetailsOnLoad();
  }, [apiInstance, product.id]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getNextAvailableTimeOnLoad() {
      setIsLoading(true)
      try {
        const time = await getNextAvailableTime(apiInstance, product.id);
        if (time.status === 200) {
          setNextAvailableTime(time.data);
        }
        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error getting next available time: ", e);
      }
      setIsLoading(false)
    }
    getNextAvailableTimeOnLoad();
  }, [apiInstance, product.id]);
```

Of course I can just track two independent loading states like this:

```
  const [firstLoader, setFirstLoader] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [secondLoader, setSecondLoader] = useState<boolean>(false);
```

...but if I don't have to, I'd rather not. It would make the code simpler and conditional rendering simpler as well for my use-case.

Comment: Not sure if this is just an artifact of example code, but you appear to be setting loading to `true`, then calling an asynchronous operation, then immediately setting loading to `false` even though the async operation hasn't necessarily completed yet...

Comment: Sorry yes, artifact of example code. I'll update the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are *guaranteed* that the two asynchronous effects will not run at the same time (for instance, if `OperationTwo`, if one is called at the completion of `OperationOne`) then  you could get away with using a single `isLoading` boolean, set as `true` at the start of `OperationOne`, and set as `false` at the completion of `OperationTwo`.

However, if you have two operations that might at any point run at the same time, then you should split them into two separate loaders, and use a single value that `OR`s them to determine the ultimate loading state of the view.

Let's consider a component that makes two asynchronous fetches on load:

```
const MyPretendComponent = () => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      MyService.fetchThatCompletesInOneSecond()
        .then(() => setIsLoading(false));
      MyService.fetchThatCompletesInTwentySeconds()
        .then(() => setIsLoading(false));
    }, [])
    
    return (<h1>{`isLoading ? "Loading" : "Finished!"`}</h1>);
}
```

This should illustrate the problem nicely-- we have two asynchronous operations on component load-- one that completes in one second, and one that completes in *twenty* seconds.  Both set `isLoading` as `false` when they complete.  In this case, the first operation completes in one second and sets `isLoading` to `false`, and the UI erroneously reports that it is not in a loading state even though the second operation still has nineteen seconds left until it completes.

The cleaner version, using two booleans, is this:

```js
const MyPretendComponent = () => {
    const [isFirstOperationLoading, setIsFirstOperationLoading] = useState(false);
    const [isSecondOperationLoading, setIsSecondOperationLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      setIsFirstOperationLoading(true);
      setIsSecondOperationLoading(true)
      MyService.fetchThatCompletesInOneSecond()
        .then(() => setIsFirstOperationLoading(false));
      MyService.fetchThatCompletesInTwentySeconds()
        .then(() => setIsSecondOperationLoading(false));
    }, [])
    
    const isLoading = isFirstOperationLoading || isSecondOperationLoading;
    
    return (<h1>{`isLoading ? "Loading" : "Finished!"`}</h1>);
}
```

Here we've split the two loading states into their own discrete booleans.  We still maintain a single `isLoading` boolean that simply `OR`s both the discrete booleans to determine if the **overall** loading state of the component is loading or not loading.  Note that, in a real-life example, we would want to use much more semantically descriptive variable names than `isFirstOperationLoading` and `isSecondOperationLoading`.

**In regards to splitting the two calls into separate `useEffect`s:** at a glance one might think that in splitting the two calls across two different `useEffect`s you could mitigate or sidestep the issue of asynchronicity.  However, if we walk through the component lifecycle, and think we will learn that this is not actually effective.  Let's update our first example:

```
const MyPretendComponent = () => {
    const [isFirstOperationLoading, setIsFirstOperationLoading] = useState(false);
    const [isSecondOperationLoading, setIsSecondOperationLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      setIsFirstOperationLoading(true);
      setIsSecondOperationLoading(true)
      MyService.fetchThatCompletesInOneSecond()
        .then(() => setIsFirstOperationLoading(false));
      MyService.fetchThatCompletesInTwentySeconds()
        .then(() => setIsSecondOperationLoading(false));
    }, [])
    
    const isLoading = isFirstOperationLoading || isSecondOperationLoading;
    
    return (<h1>{`isLoading ? "Loading" : "Finished!"`}</h1>);
}
```

The problem here is that the component does ***not*** run in this manner:

1. Run the first `useEffect`
2. When the first `useEffect` completes, run the second `useEffect`
3. When the second `useEffect` completes, render the UI

If it ran in that manner, we would be sitting and waiting for it to show the UI while it loaded.

Instead, the way it runs is like this:

1. Run the component render-- call any `useEffect`s if applicable, then render the UI
2. Should any state updates occur (for instance, a state hook being called from the `.then` of a previous `useEffect` asynchronous call) then render again
3. Repeat step two every time a state or prop update occurs

Keeping this in mind, at *every component render* React will evaluate and run *any and all* applicable `useEffect` callbacks.  It is not running them serially and tracking if one has completed-- such a thing would be difficult if not impossible.  Instead, it is the developer's responsibility to track loading states and organize `useEffect` dependency arrays in such a way that your component state is logical and consistent.

So you see, separating the async calls by `useEffect` does not save us from dealing with potential concurrent async calls.  In fact, if it did, it would mean that the UI load would be slower overall, because you would be serially calling two calls that could be called simultaneously.  For instance, if both async calls took ten seconds each, calling them one after the other would mean it would take 20 seconds before loading would be completes, as opposed to running them at the same time and finishing loading after only ten seconds.  It makes sense from a lifecycle perspective for the component to behave this way; we simply must code accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for this thoughtful reply. If I may complicate things slightly more, my question includes the added wrinkle of multiple useEffect calls. The reason this is important to my thinking is that React runs the useEffects in the order they are written in the code. So my instinct was to assume that using one boolean is okay given the predictable order of useEffect calls.


So to expand your helpful answer a bit -- would the same advice apply if `fetchThatCompletesInOneSecond` is in its own useEffect, and `fetchThatCompletesInTwentySeconds` is in its own useEffect as well?

Comment: Yes, give me a moment to update my answer to speak specifically to this point.

Comment: Updated with `useEffect` consideration.

Answer (score 1):

As @alexander-nied already pointed out there might by a bug in your code. useEffect callbacks can't be async. To use async/await nontheless you can wrap the three lines as follows and add an await statement.

```
// Version 1, closer to the original example
useEffect(() => {
    async doSomething() {
        await someAsyncMethod();
    }

    (async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        await doSomething();
        setIsLoading(false);
    })();
})

// Version 2, closer to the current example
useEffect(() => {
    async doSomething() {
        setIsLoading(true);
        await someAsyncMethod();
        setIsLoading(false);
    }

    doSomething();
})
```

To answer your question:
It certainly depends on you usecase, but I would recommend against just using one single boolean, since it allows for weired scenarios to occur.

What if one request is way faster than the other? Your loading indicator would be set to false, instead of informing the user that there is still work being done in the background.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I ask because everything I've read seems to indicate the way I am doing it is correct: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-use-async-function-in-react-hook-useeffect-typescript-js-6204a788a435

Comment: also last code block here uses the same pattern

https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/using-async-await-inside-react-use-effect-hook

Comment: Pretty sure about that yes. The first link you've posted has a similar code snippet in their Bonus/TLDR section. It's important to note the subtle differences. The first article you've linked has an example where it's not important to await the results of the async method.

Comment: okay i'm still pretty sure the way i am writing the useEffect is correct. I remembered that I got this from Dan Abramov.

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14326

Comment: You've updated your example in the meantime and the problem @alexander pointed out and I addressed is not there anymore. Now your example is totally fine. For the sake of completeness, I will update this answer to reflect the initial problem.